# How to implement a file system for operating system development

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, filesystems, osdev

I am using Xfce Ubuntu and building on GCC 10.2. I want to use FAT filesystem or EXT2 filesystem for my hobbyist operating system. I want a specific instruction and specific code for this question, and I am using C to develop my OS. I I want to list directories, make files, read files, and more in the OS. In addition, one is making an 32 bit Protected OS and I use my own kernel, which is not based on Linux or such. Means that I don't have any additional drivers or such. Please help me: how to can I use a filesystem in C (or C++, but I like C more than it) for my own OS?

Answer (score 4):

> How to implement a file system for operating system development

You first need to read a [text book about operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).

You don't *use* a file system, you *implement* yours. For inspiration, look into [Ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2), [VFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#VFAT), [XFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS). Study their source code inside the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/) source.

Of course, you'll need some compiler, so port [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (as a cross-compiler) to your OS.

See also [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/) and [Linux From Scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/)

### Budget several years of full time development efforts.